# Comparing Proportion of Positive Tests

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, proportion, log-linear

A condition or disease (***D***) is measured using two different methods (***A*** and ***B***) in a sample of 1,000 individuals from a population. Using method ***A***, the percentage of positive cases is 25%, whereas method ***B*** yields 30%.

Is there a test of statistical significance I can apply to compare method ***A*** and method ***B***? How can we test for whether these different percentages are wide enough to conclude that we are dealing with two methods of testing for ***D*** that are essentially different beyond statistical noise?

I was assuming that it would amount to testing two different proportions, but when I plug the data and analyze it with ***R*** I realize that the categorical options for method **A** and **B** are identical (i.e. positive and negative), and the comparison of proportions doesn't make sense.

It's a basic question, but I'm stuck... Here is the data:

```
  str(dat)
 'data.frame':  1000 obs. of  2 variables:
      $ Method.A: Factor w/ 2 levels "neg","pos": 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ Method.B: Factor w/ 2 levels "neg","pos": 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...


    summary(dat)
    Method.A  Method.B 
    neg:574   neg:488  
    pos:426   pos:512 


   countdf
      Method.A Method.B Freq
    1      neg      neg  302
    2      pos      neg  186
    3      neg      pos  272
    4      pos      pos  240
```

Clearly the methods are different, with Method B tending to show more positives (True or False), but if I try to run a Chi-square test it will show a statistically significant ***p*** value, implying correlation between both Methods, which of course it's there because both methods attempt to detect the disease, and neither one is awful.

What I need is to show that they are different in the way they go about detecting ***D***, because they can't possibly be equivalent when the positives for Method B are 512 while Method A only flags 426 subjects as positive.

Just for completeness:

```
Percentage table:
        Method.B
Method.A  neg  pos Total Count
     neg 52.6 47.4   100   574
     pos 43.7 56.3   100   426

    2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity
    correction

data:  .Table
X-squared = 7.8415, df = 1, p-value = 0.005106
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.02716934 0.15185603
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.5261324 0.4366197
```

---

Following the lead of another thread of discussion vis-a-vis Agresti's matched observations ([Testing paired frequencies for independence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5171/testing-paired-frequencies-for-independence)), I went one step further in my answer, and came up with the following results.

Of note, I realize that I am treating these values as ordinal, and methodologically it is a stretch, but I'm getting the same result applying a `poisson glm`.

```
two_by_two<-matrix(c(240,186,272,302),nrow=2,byrow=T)
dimnames(two_by_two) <- list(c("pos","neg"),c("pos","neg"))
names(dimnames(two_by_two)) <-c("Method.A","Method.B")
require(vcd)
library(gnm)
tab <- data.frame(counts=c(two_by_two), Method.A=gl(2,1,4,labels=c("neg","pos")),
                     Method.B=gl(2,2,4,labels=c("neg","pos")))
tab$scores <- rep(c("neg","pos"), each=2)
summary(fit <- gnm(counts ~ scores + Symm(Method.A,Method.B), data=tab, 
                       family=poisson))

Call:

gnm(formula = counts ~ scores + Symm(Method.A, Method.B), family = poisson, 
    data = tab)

Deviance Residuals: 
[1]  0  0  0  0

Coefficients:
                               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                     5.48064    0.06455  84.906  < 2e-16 ***
scorespos                      -0.38006    0.09515  -3.994 6.48e-05 ***
Symm(Method.A, Method.B)negpos  0.12516    0.08856   1.413    0.158    
Symm(Method.A, Method.B)pospos  0.60984    0.12857   4.743 2.10e-06 ***
```

And my follow up question is whether it would be appropriate to interpret the results as: The probability that Method.B is “neg” when Method.A scores “pos” is exp(-0.38006) =  0.68382 times the probability that Method.B has a “pos” score while Method.A has a “neg” score?

Here are for comparison two poisson glm fits:

```
summary(fit.symm <- glm(counts ~ scores + Symm(Method.A,Method.B), 
                        family = poisson(log),data = tab))

Coefficients:
                               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                     5.48064    0.06455  84.906  < 2e-16 ***
scorespos                      -0.38006    0.09515  -3.994 6.48e-05 ***
Symm(Method.A, Method.B)negpos  0.12516    0.08856   1.413    0.158    
Symm(Method.A, Method.B)pospos  0.60984    0.12857   4.743 2.10e-06 ***
```

And,

```
    summary(fit.symm <- glm(counts ~ Symm(Method.A,Method.B), 
                            family = poisson(log),data = tab))
Call:
glm(formula = counts ~ Symm(Method.A, Method.B), family = poisson(log), 
    data = tab)

Deviance Residuals: 
     1       2       3       4  
 0.000   2.759  -2.938   0.000  

Coefficients:
                               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                     5.48064    0.06455  84.906  < 2e-16 ***
Symm(Method.A, Method.B)negpos -0.04692    0.07969  -0.589  0.55602    
Symm(Method.A, Method.B)pospos  0.22979    0.08647   2.657  0.00788 **
```

Is this last model best? Would then the conclusion be: The probability that Method.B is “neg” when Method.A scores “pos” is exp(-0.04692) =  0.954 times the probability that Method.B has a “pos” score while Method.A has a “neg” score?

Comment: Do you have information about the full $2\times 2$ contingency table?  That is, do you have the proportions who were positive for both A and B, positive for A but not for B, etc.?

Comment: I have included the information I have in the question. I know it has to be a really obvious conceptual problem - it's like I want the opposite of a Fisher test or a Chi-square test... Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. Here's what I got so far, and I hope this is *the* answer:

The right test for this situation in which the same data is looked at with different prisms, or there is a before and after treatment setup, and with the variables being categorical leading to proportions and *2 x 2* contingency tables, is the **McNemar test**.

In this test what we look to see if whether the effect of different "methods" (to follow the terminology in my question above), or the changes between pre- and post-treatment counts affects the diagonal columns of the contingency table:

```
        Method.B
Method.A neg pos
     neg 302 272
     pos 186 240
```

If both methods were interchangeable, one would like to see a table such as:

```
        Method.B
Method.A neg pos
     neg a    0
     pos 0    d
```

When one test yields a negative result, so does the other test (or "method"); same for positive results.

So it is the magnitude of these diagonal cells when they are different from zero (let's call them *b* and *c*) that are the fundamental of the McNemar test:

The McNemar test statistic is:

$\chi^2 = {(b-c)^2 \over b+c}$.

So the more discrepant these diagonal values are $(b - c)^2$, the larger the $\chi^2$ value, and the more likely will it be that we are dealing with different "methods" - the proportions of Method A are different from Method B.

To call the test in ***R***:

```
two_by_two <- table(dat)

two_by_two
        Method.B
Method.A neg pos
     neg 302 272
     pos 186 240

 mcnemar.test(two_by_two, correct = F) #No correction generally needed.

McNemar's Chi-squared test

data:  two_by_two
McNemar's chi-squared = 16.1485, df = 1, p-value = 5.857e-05
```

And there it is: Method B tends to yield more positive results when measuring the presence of disease, ***D***, and the ***p*** value of accepting $H_1$ is ridiculously small.